# Proof for $\langle i[A,B]\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

I have to prove the following equation:
$$
\langle i[A,B]\rangle = 2\mathfrak{Im}\left[\int dV(\overline{B\psi)}(A\psi)\right]\,,$$
where A,B are hermitian operators.
Here is my calculation, but I don't get the right result. Can you help me to find my mistake?

$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle i[A,B]\rangle &=(\psi,i[A,B]\psi)
\\&=(\psi,i(AB-BA)\psi)
\\&=(\psi,iAB\psi-iBA\psi)
\\&=(\psi,iAB\psi)-(\psi,iBA\psi)
\\&=i(A^\dagger\psi,B\psi)-i(B^\dagger\psi,A\psi)
\\&=i(A\psi,B\psi)-i(B\psi,A\psi)
\\&=-i[(B\psi,A\psi)-(A\psi,B\psi)]
\\&=-i[(B\psi,A\psi)-\overline{(B\psi,A\psi)}]
\\&=-2i\,\mathfrak{Im}[(B\psi,A\psi)]
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake is in the last line. Using the following identity helps to get the result what you are seeking for. $$ (a+ib)-(a-ib)=2ib=2i Im(a+ib) $$